# Callback from SQL when there is a insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a simple application that is showing the users a status of 10 different database values.
The values in the database is updating by a 3part software and the update rate is down to every 1 seconds for some of the values and other 1-2 hours.

I need a way of getting a event call back from the SQL when there is an INSERT of “Name X” in the table.

To day my app is doing a select query to look for change every 1seconds. 
But I do not think this is good practice. If many users is using this app. It will be a big load on the SQL server I think.

What will be the best solution to look for updates like this?

Comment: You want a [SQL trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341584/sql-server-after-insert-trigger-update-another-column-in-the-same-table)

Comment: You could use [Sql Dependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Liam I'd rather go with a [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watch for a table new records in sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225147/watch-for-a-table-new-records-in-sql-database)

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to this posts.

Comment: If I understand this right,this solution will give me a callback on every insert/update. Bu I just need a call back on the update/inserts of a specific Value. (Insert where the Name=xx”) 
The table has updates every seconds, but my app is just monitoring some values and they are updated only 1min to 1houer. And I only need a trigger event on this updates.

Comment: Using a trigger is a viable option. Though it locks the table.
Please check this before you move forward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606226/sql-server-2008-running-trigger-after-insert-update-locks-original-table