# Update column every 24 hours

Tags: sql-server

I have a column of values and I need it to update every 24 hours decreasing the maximum value by 1 until it reaches 0, and after that SQL will delete it. How could I do this on SQL Server?

Comment: What has your research show you? This is a frequently asked question.

Comment: maybe I haven't seen it, but I looked

Comment: The engine itself does not do this. You will need to _schedule_ (hint) something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958990/update-record-inserted-in-table-after-one-hour

Comment: unsuccessful with Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: That was just the first result of my google search... there were loads...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [stored procedure](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp) that runs the code and schedule it using [SQL Agent.](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15)